# How to read data using Hibernate after many to many mapping

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

[image]

I have two tables Role and Right, and hibernate created 1 table role_right as a result of Many to Many mapping.

Now I want to get all **RightName** corresponding to **RoleName** seperately
like

```
admin--> create user, data entry, login, logout

data entry operator--> data entry, logout, login

data analyst--> data analysis, logout, login
```

Help me to solve this. here is my code

**UserRole class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserRole")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="RoleID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int roleId;
    @Column(name="RoleName", nullable=false)
    private String roleName;
    @Column(name="RoleRight")
    private String roleRight;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="Role_Right",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Role_Id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Right_Id"))
    private Collection<UserRights> userRoleMapping = new ArrayList<UserRights>();

    public Collection<UserRights> getUserRoleMapping() {
        return userRoleMapping;
    }

    public void setUserRoleMapping(Collection<UserRights> userRoleMapping) {
        this.userRoleMapping = userRoleMapping;
    }

    public String getRoleRight() {
        return roleRight;
    }

    public void setRoleRight(String roleRight) {
        this.roleRight = roleRight;
    }

    public int getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    } 
}
```

**UserRole class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserRights")
public class UserRights implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="RightID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int rightId;
    @Column(name="RightName", nullable=false)
    private String rightName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="userRoleMapping")
    private Collection<UserRole> userRightsMapping = new ArrayList<UserRole>();

    public Collection<UserRole> getUserRightsMapping() {
        return userRightsMapping;
    }

    public void setUserRightsMapping(Collection<UserRole> userRightsMapping) {
        this.userRightsMapping = userRightsMapping;
    }

    public int getRightId() {
        return rightId;
    }

    public void setRightId(int rightId) {
        this.rightId = rightId;
    }

    public String getRightName() {
        return rightName;
    }

    public void setRightName(String rightName) {
        this.rightName = rightName;
    } 
}
```

I tried some thing like this

```
session.getUserRightsMapping()
```

this query is very close to what i want

String query = "select Role_Id, RightName FROM userrights join role_right on "
+ "userrights.RightID = role_right.Right_Id";

but don't know what to do further

Comment: What have you tried? How about calling `role.getRights()` and iterating through each right to get its name?

Comment: i have added my code in question please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to make things clearer, I would start by renaming your entities and fields:

- `UserRole`, with a collection of rights named... `rights`
- `UserRight` (without s), with a collection of roles named... `roles`

Now, the simplest thing to do is just to get all the roles, and to fetch the rights of each role in a single query:

```
String hql = "select role from UserRole role left join fetch role.rights";
List<UserRole> roles = session.createQuery(hql).list()
// now you can iteratr through the roles, and for each role, iterate through its rights
```

If you really just want to have all the role_name/right_name associations, then use the following code:

```
String hql = "select role.name, right.name from UserRole role"
             + " inner join role.rights right";
List<Object[]> rows = session.createQuery(hql).list();
```

And each Object[] element of the returned list contains two elements: the role name and the right name. Note that the roles which don't have any right are not returned by this query.

All this is very well explained in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins). Read it.